# Linker error in iPhone5 for Spotify

Tags: iphone, spotify, iphone-5, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I am implementing Spotify in my iPhone app. In iPhone4 and 4S, it builds and runs fine. But when I connected iPhone5 device and builds, it shows linker error. After disconnecting the device, the build is again success. What may be the reason. Please help me.

Comment: try disabling building for armv7s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application's Build Settings, find the "Valid Architectures" setting and remove armv7s from the list. libspotify doesn't include an armv7s architecture yet, but the plain armv7 build will work perfectly fine on the iPhone 5.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It worked fine for me. But for build success, I had to make "Build Active Architecture Only" settings to NO. Is there any problem if that settings is NO. Please confirm.

Comment: What you did is correct. Make sure you upvote and mark my answer as the correct answer if it's been helpful.